Forward Rate of a Forward Rate. (calculate 1y1y rate in 1m time)
I'm sure this is straightforward and I am just missing something.
I am familiar with standard fwd rate calculations. i.e assuming a 2y swap rate is x and a 1y swap rate is y, the 1y1y rate would be approx. (assuming annual compounding etc)
((1+x)^2/(1+y)^1) - 1

But if I'm looking at swaps, and I have the 1y1y rate now, and i wanted to find the mkt expectation of a 1y1y rate in 1m time. How do i get there?

A 1y1y rate in 1m time as measured from the curve is the same as a 13m1y rate from today. There is nothing more you can do other than attempt to calculate the rate over which the effective and termination dates are desired. (Note that while that formula is usually used for bond ytm forwards, it is not always very good for swaps. If you can calculate discount factors there is a better, actually exact formula, that can be used)
